# Creating Web Deploy Package in VS 2013. Updating Parameter.xml during creation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

So I haven't made Web Deploy Packages before. It has been straight forward thus far but I am having trouble figuring out one last thing.

In the parameters.xml file that is generated inside the .zip file when it is published. There is a parameter node. Which looks like this:

```
<parameter name="IIS Web Application Name" defaultValue="Default Web Site/*my application name*" tags="IisApp"/>
```

By default the 'name' attribute has the "IIS Web Application Name" for it's value. I need it to change but I am having difficulty doing that. I was reading through the documentation on msdn and such and it looked like there was a way to do it by adding a parameters section in the Web.config file with either one of these nodes from what I understand.

```
<setParameter/>
```

or

```
<parameterEntry/>
```

obviously there are attributes for each. But what I have read in the documentation either of these should work. Either that or I am not understanding it properly.

I have done some looking here as well but haven't found anything that has worked yet. Does anyone know what I have to do to update the default attribute 'name' to what I want in VS 2013? Or at least point me in the right direction. The documentation I have found seems to be at least 3 years old.

Thanks

Comment: Dont those values come from your publishing profile xml file?

Comment: I see the defaultValue attribute's value in the pubxml in this xml node <DeployIisAppPath> but I don't know what attribute to add or attribute that is there that I would need to update so that the parameter name attribute in the parameter xml file gets populated.

Comment: Sorry, I misread that you are trying to change the value, not the name of the parameter.  Can I ask why you need to change the parameter's name? Perhaps we can come up with a different solution to your problem.